# Why can't I the properties of properties when looping an object?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this object:

```
const people = {
     frodo: { name: 'Frodo', age: 33 },
     aragorn: { name: 'Aragorn', age: 87 },
     legolas: { name: 'Legolas', age: 2931 }
}
```

And let's say I want to loop over the properties of that object, like this:

```
for (var person in people) {
    console.log(person.name);
}
```

I get undefined for any property of the person I tried to access. Why does this happen, and what's the correct way to loop the properties of that object and still be able to access their own properties?

Comment: see this post, you can find all ways to loop over object properties in JS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5737136/6171845

Answer (score 2):

The for ... in loop iterates over the keys (properties) of an object. So

```
for (var person in people) {
  console.log(people[person].name);
}
```

will get you the desired result.

The variable `person` will receive the values "frodo", "aragorn" and "legolas" during the execution of the loop which are the keys (properties) of your person object.

Answer (score 2):

You take the keys of the object with [`for ... in` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). Then you need it as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) fopr the object.

```js
const people = {
     frodo: { name: 'Frodo', age: 33 },
     aragorn: { name: 'Aragorn', age: 87 },
     legolas: { name: 'Legolas', age: 2931 }
}

for (var person in people) {
    console.log(people[person].name);
}
```

Comment: Or `for..of`, surely.

Comment: `for of` works only for objects with implemented [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator).

Comment: Indeed. I didn't look closely enough.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at what `person` is within your code:

```js
const people = {
     frodo: { name: 'Frodo', age: 33 },
     aragorn: { name: 'Aragorn', age: 87 },
     legolas: { name: 'Legolas', age: 2931 }
}

for(person in people) console.log(person);
```

It's the name of the object, not the object itself. To access it you need to specify where the object is located:

```js
  const people = {
         frodo: { name: 'Frodo', age: 33 },
         aragorn: { name: 'Aragorn', age: 87 },
         legolas: { name: 'Legolas', age: 2931 }
    }

    for(person in people) {
      console.log( people[person].age, people[person].name, people[person] );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

for .. in returns every key in the object. You can get the person by using the key.

```
const people = {
     frodo: { name: 'Frodo', age: 33 },
     aragorn: { name: 'Aragorn', age: 87 },
     legolas: { name: 'Legolas', age: 2931 }
}

for(var key in people) {
    var person = people[key]
    console.log(person.name)
}
```